# How do I populate a drop-down list with foreach loop and range() function in php

Tags: php

Im trying to show a date the user picks with a drop down box in php. In my code Im using the range function to have a start and stop, then Im using a loop to populate the drop down by one. Except it only shows the ending number in range. How do I fix it so the drop down box shows the year 1921-2021?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected"></option>
        <?php
        foreach (range(1921,2021,1) as $Years){  
            echo "$Years, ";  
        } 
        // A sample product array
        $products = array("$Years");
        
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($products as $item){
            echo "<option selected ='strtolower($item)'>$item</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need the `$products` related part? Would it be possible to use the `<option></option>` part inside of the `range()` related loop?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you rewrite your `$Years` variable in every loop.

You shoud make array of values and iterate them later

```
<?php
   // A sample product array
   $products = array();

   foreach (range(1921,2021,1) as $Years){  
        echo "$Years, ";
        $products[] = $Years;  <---- add year into array
   }
        
   // Iterating through the product array
   foreach($products as $item){
       echo "<option selected ='strtolower($item)'>$item</option>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code with one foreach:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <select>
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <?php
                foreach (range(1921, 2021, 1) as $each_years) {
                    echo "<option selected ='strtolower($each_years)'>$each_years</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```